# como instalar el paquete php-unoconv en php

Tags: php

buen día, estoy intentando realizar la instalación del paquete php-unoconv que es de php la idea es poderlo instalar en Orfeo el sistema libre, pero en la documentación oficial del paquete que esta en este link https://github.com/alchemy-fr/PHP-Unoconv no veo como empezar, agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar

Comment: Ahí en el README sugieren usar composer. ¿Sabes cómo usarlo?

Answer (score 1):

**Paso 1** Instala `composer`  [url](https://getcomposer.org/)

**Paso 2** Abre una terminal en **windows**    `windows + R`

**Paso 3** Desde la terminal navega a tu proyecto  con el comando  `cd`

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\tuproyecto**
```

**paso 3**  crea una capeta en tu proyecto  para almacenar la libreria con el comando `mkdir "nombre_carpeta"`

**paso 4**  entra a la carpeta que has creado  `cd nombre_carpeta`

**paso 5** utiliza el comando de composer :  `composer require php-unoconv/php-unoconv`

Tienes un video por [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2BBkMO9RiM&themeRefresh=1)